Creating an Electron/Hole - doped band structure in Quantum Espresso
Apolgies if this has been asked before I am still very new to QE
Previously I have calculated the band structure for different (undoped) 2D materials, which has passed through relax calculations and pw.x to eventually get the band structures.
Now I am interested in looking at how to include some form of electron or hole-doping, I have seen that we can charge 'tot_charge=' in pw.x to add or remove charge in the unit cell accounting for the electron and hole. Therefore for a single electron or hole doping, I assume you follow through with the relax and normal band structure procedure with tot_charge= $\pm$ 1?
